# Merging data frame with overlapping columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following DataFrames:

```
    stores = [['AA', 12, 'Red'], ['BB', 13, 'Red'], ['BB', 14, 'Red'], ['BB', 15, 'Red']]
    visits = [['BB', 13, 'Green'], ['BB', 14, 'Blue']]

    stores_df = pd.DataFrame(data=stores, columns=['retailer', 'store', 'color'])
    stores_df.set_index(['retailer', 'store'], inplace=True)

    visits_df = pd.DataFrame(data=visits, columns=['retailer', 'store', 'color'])
    visits_df.set_index(['retailer', 'store'], inplace=True)

                color
retailer store       
BB       13     Green
         14      Blue

               color
retailer store      
AA       12      Red
BB       13      Red
         14      Red
         15      Red
```

How I can merge them in order to get following result:

```
               color
retailer store      
AA       12      Red
BB       13      Green
         14      Blue
         15      Red
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `update`:

```
In [41]: stores_df.update(visits_df)

In [42]: stores_df
Out[42]:
                color
retailer store
AA       12       Red
BB       13     Green
         14      Blue
         15       Red
```

Comment: This is a great answer.  `update` changes inplace and does not have a return value.  These are features that can be useful.  +1

Comment: I actually prefer much more combine_first. Changing inplace and no return is stabbing you in your back. I am far more keen on a functional paradigm where you do not modify the object and you have a return value: a copy of the object, modified.

Comment: True and I agree.  But I wasn't aware of an `update` on dataframes.  I'll keep it in mind for potential future use.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `combine_first`

```
visits_df.combine_first(stores_df)
```

[image]